# Azure API APP authentication using Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication

I'm a bit confused regarding the **authentication/authorization** setting on the settings blade for an Web/Api App in Azure.

If I enable Azure AD authentication via the portal.
Is there any way to get hold of user information in the actual service then?
I know there is the `Bearer` security header, but can I extract any useful information from that?

Or is the **authentication/authorization** setting acting only as a proxy before the call to the service. that is, it requires valid AD credentials, but the service never have to deal with any of the details around it?

What would be the main differences between using that setting vs. creating an Web/Api App that uses Asp.NET authentication via code. e.g. its possible to set that up using the standard ASp.NET templates.
In those templates you get an OWIN app that uses an Azure AD authentication provider.

If I use the latter, is there any benefit from the **authentication/authorization** setting? or can I simply ignore that if the App itself has an authentication provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the authentication in the portal allows you to get some very rudimentary information about the logged-on user via the header "X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME", and you also have access to whatever claims are passed in. There's a good example here: [Websites-Authentication-Authorization](https://github.com/btardif/Websites-Authentication-Authorization#websites-authentication-authorization)

Comment: So the idea is that you use either or so to say?

Comment: yep. The "portal-enabled" authentication came much later than the ADAL library. The latter provides a much richer environment, but for simple authentication/basic user info stuff the former should work just fine, is my understanding.